# How to join two KTable and write the result ktable in state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two KTable objects:

```
KTable<Long, byte[]> firstTable = builder.table("firstTopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray()));

 KTable<Long, byte[]> secondTable = builder.table("secondTopic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray()));
```

After that I want to join these two tables:

```
firstTable.leftJoin(secondTable,
            (leftValue, rightValue) -> {
            try {
                return utils.serializeNetwork(utils.deserializeNetwork(leftValue));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            }
          )
```

So I have two  tables and I'm joining them into one  table, and I want the resulted table to be stored in the kafka state store by each key, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force a materialization into a local store by specifying `Materialized` parameter on `leftJoin` and specify a name for the state store.

```java
firstTable.leftJoin(..., Materialized.as("my-store-name"));
```